# Show content field information in page layout

Tags: 2013, page-layout

I have a mandatory field (published date) used for a content type.  I want to display this info in the page layout.  I have done this using SPD to edit the page.  My code looks like this `<i>Article Date: </i><SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField  FieldName="ea266b0f-51ec-4fd3-bdcf-0c010a4caea7" runat="server" ></SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField>`

BUT when you create a new page using the new layout it is wanting the publishing date entered twice.  HOw can I just display what is entered in this field in the page layout with out the prompt for the same info again?

Comment: is the mandatory field was added in edit mode panel ?

Comment: Yes it's there in effect twice I guess.  Once for the end user to fill in (date and time)  The second instance just needs to be the date(display only).  As I couldn't do this (the original field needs to be date and time)  I have trimmed display of the field.  Would a better option to display a crawled managed property in the page?